# How to pass multiple PHP get parameters

Tags: php, html, get

In this code, I'm trying to take a user that wants to change event statuses from a dropdown. The dropdown consists of three options:

"Contacted"
"Verified"
"Completed"

I want a user to click "Submit status" and take them to change.php, as specified in the action attribute. Change.php should have 2 get parameters: the id of the database column of the event they want to alter, and the new status they want to change it to. For example it should look like this: http://localhost/schedule/change.php?id=60?status=verified

But this is what I'm getting right now:

http://localhost/schedule/change.php?status=verified&submitStatus=Change+status

And also, the dropdown is showing an error: Notice: Undefined index: status in line 1

```
 // Assume this is line 1
 echo "<form method='get' action='change.php?id=".urlencode($e['id'])."?url=".urlencode($_GET['status'])."'><select name='status' id='status'>'";

    if ($e['status'] == "contacted") {

      echo "<option value='contacted' selected>Contacted</option>";

      echo "<option value='verified'>Verified Appointment</option>";

      echo "<option value='completed'>Job Completed</option>";

      $counter++;

    } else if ($e['status'] == "verified") {

      echo "<option value='verified' selected>Verified Appointment</option>";

      echo "<option value='contacted'>Contacted</option>";

      echo "<option value='completed'>Job Completed</option>";

      $counter++;

    } else if ($e['status'] == "completed") {

      echo "<option value='completed' selected>Job Completed</option>";

      echo "<option value='contacted'>Contacted</option>";

      echo "<option value='verified' selected>Verified Appointment</option>";

      $counter++;

    } else {

      echo "No event status found!";

    }

    if ($counter == 1) {

    echo "<input type='submit' name='submitStatus' value='Change status'></form></select>
    </td>"; 

    echo "</tr>";

  }
```

I know the real issue lies in the first echo line, where I start the form tag, and I know the issue is in the action parameter, but I just don't know what to do! Please help me out here...

Comment: Query string parameters are separate by `&`, not more `?`. Also, any query parameters you set in a `GET` form's `action` will be lost and overwritten with whatever named elements are within the form. I suggest you use `method="post"` if you want to maintain both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that you are using `?` to separate parameters instead of using `&` or `&&`. So your code should be:

```
 echo "<form method='get' action='change.php?id=".urlencode($e['id'])."&url=".urlencode($_GET['status'])."'><select name='status' id='status'>'";
```

Also, as said by Phil, try using `POST` if you don't want to change the data values from url. For example, if you change, `id` from url, change.php will make changes on the basis of `id` parameter from url. It seems to me like you should use `POST` as **change** to me means quite secure thing and not the thing to be done via `GET`.

Obviously, it does not mean you should not use `GET`. These methods are equally important, but not as secure in the sense that data can be changed from url so easily. `GET` can be used in search process, for example where you don't have to change to the database, you just have to retrive.

I might have gone off topic, but I think that was quite important for you to know which method you should be using. Thank you!!!